# jQuery post error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I am posting data from a form to a PHP page through jQuery.

Below is the code. Let me know if you need to see the code from the php or html pages.

```
$("#createQuestionForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("check1");
    $.post("InsertNewQuestion.php", $("#createQuestionForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {
        alert("check2");
    });
});
```

I can see the first alert("check1") but the problem is that I cannot see the second alert("check2"). What is the problem?

------------------------------------------AFTER EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------

I found the problem: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'done', how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you debug this?  Are there any console errors in the browser?  Is a request successfully made to `InsertNewQuestion.php`?  What is the response to that request?

Comment: I dont think there is any problem in the php file because when I use the html file to submit the data directly to php without javascript as the middleman, there is no error.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser tools, what gets returned?

Comment: Whether or not there is a problem in the PHP file is immaterial.  You need to examine the actual request to and response from the server.  There could be an error that you're ignoring.

Comment: On the network tab this is the information that is given. Name: InsertNewQuestion.php, Method: POST, Status: 200 OK, Type: text/html, Initiator: Other, Size: 221B 0B, Time: 10ms 9ms, Then there is a blue bar in the Timeline tab that stops near 11ms.

Comment: How do I check the request and response from the server?

Comment: I usually use jquery ajaxForm plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm
It's easy to use and understand. You don't need to serialize the data (the plugin do it) and you can execute functions before and after the post request.

Comment: The firebug shows these errors: Timestamp: 3/6/2013 11:22:06 AM
Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Source File: http://localhost/QuizAdminWebpage/InsertNewQuestion.php
Line: 0

Comment: @Curlas I will keep that in mind. If this does not work out then I will try that out. However as I have been working on this aspect of the project for a long time I just want to get it over with.

Comment: @VedaSadhak What happens if you just enter that URL into your browser directly? Do you get what you'd expect displayed?

Comment: I assume by URL you meant the InsertNewQuestion.php. When I run that in the browser I get a few errors but those are expected as no form data is sent. Those errors are only associated with no form data being sent to InsertNewQuestion.

Comment: I found the problem: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My jQuery file was not up to date. I updated the file and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you [re-read the $.post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?:

```
$.post("InsertNewQuestion.php", $("#createQuestionForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    alert("check2");
}, 'json');
```

More about the arguments and `$.post()` options you have on the documentation website.

Comment: I have already read through the document on the jQuery website, that's where I got the code. I was not able to solve the problem using the information they had given that's why I have posted a question here.

Comment: well use it the way I wrote it in this answer. this example needs following parameters: url, data, success_callback, data_type-output.

Comment: The only difference is the 'json'. The problem with that is that it refreshes the page. If I need to parse the data I will just use parseJSON.

Comment: I don't understand. Please correct me if im wrong, that is the reason I have come to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "json" is just an output format, a data interchange format, which has nothing to do with "refreshing" or "reloading" the page!

Comment: Oh ok. With respect to parseJSON and 'json' are there any advantages to using one over the other?

Comment: what I have wrote you is just an extended example of $.post() function. it has no effect on your problem whatsoever! cheers!